# compute sum up each 2 rows and replace them with another value if the sum is less than a specific value

Tags: python, perl, bioinformatics

I have a genotype matrix (with tabular space), with 2 million rows and 12 columns. Columns are individuals and rows are SNPs. I have 2 rows per each SNP for each individual, one is the number of reference allele and the other number of alternative allele (every 2 rows correspond to one SNP which means rows 1 and 2 correspond to SNP 1, rows 3 and 4 correspond to SNP2, rows 5 and 6 correspond to SNP 3).

This is an example, (2 SNPs and 8 individuals):

```
head genotype
2   3   1   0   0   3   5   3       
18  15  19  18  16  15  13  17      
2   1   0   0   0   1   1   1           
18  19  18  16  20  17  17  23
```

For each SNP if the sum of reference and alternative allele is less than 20, I want to replace both alleles with 0, and if they are equal or more than 20 I want to keep them. This is my desired out put

```
head (desired_output)
    2   0   1   0   0   0   0   3       
    18  0   19  0   0   0   0   17      
    2   1   0   0   0   0   0   1           
    18  19  0   0   20  0   0   23
```

Any idea how to do that accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to save consecutive lines in 2 arrays, then compare the array elements by corresponding indices.

Save this to a file, say "twenty.awk"

```
#/usr/bin/env awk

# ref https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html
function join(array, start, end, sep,    result, i)
{
    if (sep == "")
        sep = " "
    else if (sep == SUBSEP) # magic value
        sep = ""
    result = array[start]
    for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
        result = result sep array[i]
    return result
}

{
    split($0, a)
    getline

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if (a[i] + $i < 20)
            a[i] = $i = 0

    print join(a, 1, NF)
    print
}
```

Then run with

```
awk -f twenty.awk data.file | column -t > data.file.twenty
```

Comment: thanks @glenn jackman. I tried your code but I get a sintext error message: vaniil.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `array,'
vaniil.sh: line 4: `function join(array, start, end, sep, result, i)'

Comment: It appears as if you're executing it as a bash script. It is awk code. Run it like I demonstrate